# Catmull-rom filter?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

As a former 3d Studio Max user, I used to use the Catmull-Rom filter to get sharp renderings. When switching to Blender, in its older versions, I was happy to see that it also had this filter.

I noticed that in the latest versions there is no longer this filter. What happened to it? Is there another way to get the same result?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Blur Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/blur_node.html) now contains the Catmull-Rom filter.

[image]

Comment: man, thank you very much.